# Would a function component that uses useState hooks be considered as stateful component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Would a component of type

```
function App() {
  const [state,  setState] = React.useState()

  return (
     [...]
  )
}
```

be considered as a stateful component by the definition? Or would be still a stateless functional component since it does not extend `React.Component` explicitly and does not declare a state with passing `super(props)`?

Best regards,
Konstantin

Comment: It maintains internal state, so I'd consider it "stateful."

Comment: yes, given that definition, it is stateful

Comment: Yes, it is. One of the reason is Hooks only can be called inside of React component. Kindly check this : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: I think having to say “useState” makes this essentially self-answering.

Comment: Depends on if you ever call `setState`, but then if you never use it, be kind of pointless code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Stateless Component** is when a component is purely a result of **props alone**, **no state**, the component can be written as a pure function avoiding the need to create a React component instance.

```
const Component = ({ name }) => {
  return <>{name}</>;
};
```

So, **if it is not stateless**, **it is a stateful** component.

```
function App() {
  const [state,setState] = React.useState()
  return <>{state}</>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every React component that has a state influences its behavior (/render) or another component's behavior can be considered as a "stateful component". So for the function in the question - yes, `App` is stateful.